# TypeError: undefined is not a function - .parent()

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jquery and playing around with navigating the tree.

```
$('.quick-info') returns a list
$('.quick-info')[0] grabs the first element in that list
```

When I try to find the parent of the first element in that list

```
$('.quick-info')[0].parent()
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$('.quick-info')[0]` returns HTMLnode, which does not have function `.parent`. Use `$('.quick-info').get(0).parent()` http://api.jquery.com/get/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call jQuery's `parent()` method on the first element of a returned set, you'll need to re-wrap it in a jQuery selector:

```
$($('.quick-info')[0]).parent();
```

...or you can use [jQuery's `first()` method](http://api.jquery.com/first/) to get the first matching element:

```
$('.quick-info').first().parent();
```

...or, as Cheery has [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26592653/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-parent/26592692#comment41800056_26592653), you can use [jQuery's `get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/) instead of `[0]`:

```
$('.quick-info').get(0).parent();
```

Otherwise you're attempting to call jQuery's `parent()` method on the HTML Node (to which that function doesn't natively exist).

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because `$('.quick-info')[0]` is a native DOM object which does not have `.parent()` function (which is a part of jQuery).

I think that what you are looking for is `.first()`:

```
$('.quick-info').first().parent()
```

Comment: in python I can do print type(obj) to inspect what kind of object it is. Is there a way to do that in javascript/jquery?

Comment: @MorganAllen No, not really. All you can do is to look at methods and/or prototype and try to figure it out from the context.